# Expo EAS Environment Variables / Secrets not readable in app

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables, dotenv

i created 2 example secrets on expo.dev for my App. When I create my development build during the build process the 2 variables are shown in the logs.

```
    Environment secrets:
    B_K=********
    SECRET_API_KEY=********
```

However when I want to access them in my App through config.js they are not being logged in my App and dont show up at all.

app.config.js

```
import 'dotenv/config'

export default ({ config }) => {
  console.log()
  const appConfig = ({
    ...config,
    //override anything you want
    extra: {
      eas: {
        "projectId": "xxx"
      },
      ksmdf:"sdfbubububs",
      B_K: process.env.B_K,
      S_K: process.env.SECRET_API_KEY,
      //...
    }
  });
  return appConfig;
}
```

in App.js when i then add following line:

```
  console.log("these r keys", Constants.expoConfig.extra)
```

only the projectId and the example variable ksmdf get logged.
How can I resolve that to use the Expo Secrets in my App????